How to add a manifest to Universal Viewer that is behind authorization?
The origin of my question comes from loading in a manifest object since the request url requires an authorization header.
I can fetch the a valid IIIF manifest but have not found a way to pass it into Universal Viewer.
The only valid option for IIIF what I have found is passing the URL via iiifManifestId as option
import { init } from 'universalviewer'

init('uv-viewer', {
  iiifManifestId: myManifestUrl
})

From the examples of the repo manifest is used but that should not make a difference with iiifManifestId according to UniversalViewer.ts#L57
What I want to be able to do is something like:
import { init } from 'universalviewer'

const myManifestData = await getManifest(myManifestUrl)

init('uv-viewer', {
  iiifManifestData: myManifestData
})

OR like what Mirador Viewer does:
import { init } from 'universalviewer'

init('uv-viewer', {
  iiifManifestId: myManifestUrl,
  requests: {
    preprocessors: [
      (options) => {
        return {
          ...options,
          headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + getToken() },
        }
      },
    ],
  },
})

I have seen GitHub issue #43 witch could resolve this issue.
However due to the lack of my understanding of Universal Viewer I wont be continuing that route. Unless the maintainers agree on my findings (in said issue).

Conal-Tuohy commented on Sep 18

Having read your Stack Overflow post, I now see that your use case is different to the one originally raised in this issue:
it's actually about authentication is it not?
A Service Worker might be a good way to intercept and authenticate the HTTPS requests made by UV

A Service Worker resolves the issue to add an authorization header to the request for Universal Vieuwer. Below you can see my implementation of the Service Worker, registration, and initialization.
I explained what is going on in the comments in the code.
UniversalViewer.worker.js
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  // Skip over the "waiting" lifecycle state, to ensure that our
  // new service worker is activated immediately, even if there's
  // another tab open controlled by our older service worker code.
  self.skipWaiting()
})

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  // Optional: Get a list of all the current open windows/tabs under
  // our service worker's control, and force them to reload.
  // This can "unbreak" any open windows/tabs as soon as the new
  // service worker activates, rather than users having to manually reload.
  self.clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then((windowClients) => {
    windowClients.forEach((windowClient) => {
      windowClient.navigate(windowClient.url)
    })
  })
})

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data?.source === 'universal-viewer') {
    token = `${event.data.token}`
  }
})

// NOTE: My regexp is more complex but it is a start to identify the iiif manifest
const manifestRegexp =
  /\/iiif\/[0-9]\/manifest\.json$/

/**
 * Catches fetch events and checks if request is made by UniversalViewer
 * @param {FetchEvent} event
 */
const fetchEvent = async (event) => {
  // Stop modification for requests that are not fit the expected iiif manifest url
  if (manifestRegexp.test(event.request.url) !== true) {
    return
  }

  const modifiedRequest = new Request(event.request, {
    headers: {
      authorization: token,
    },
  })

  event.respondWith(fetch(modifiedRequest))
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', fetchEvent)

UniversalViewer.register.ts
const name = 'UniversalViewer Worker'

export const registerUniversalViewerWorker = (token = 'No Provider') => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('/UniversalViewer.worker.js', {
        scope: '/',
        updateViaCache: 'none',
      })
      .then((registration) => {
        console.log(`${name} registered service worker`)
        registration.update()
        console.log(`${name} updated service worker`)
        registration.active?.postMessage({
          source: 'universal-viewer',
          token: `Bearer ${token}`,
        })
      })
  }
}

main.ts // NOTE: this is a simplified example on my implementation
import { registerUniversalViewerWorker } from './UniversalViewer.register'

initAuthProfider().then((provider) => {
  // other code you do with your provider

  registerUniversalViewerWorker(provider.token)
})


